# Where can I read about the topological properties of the perforated plane?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Anybody knows about perforated plane in topology? What is it? Where can I read about it?

I'm talking about the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the topology that have basis elements disks without finite lines passing through the center of the disks. Not $\mathbb{R}^2- \{0\}$.

I did not find nothing about it in the web, nor in wikipedia. Perhaps this is not the correct name, the name "plano perforado" is in spanish.

Thanks.

Comment: $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: It is usually called 'punctured plane'. You also can search for 'circle', they are similar.

Comment: @user126154 No. Consider the plane with the topology whose basis are circles without finite many lines passing through the center.

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: Sorry, what does "circles without finite many lines passing through the center" mean?  I know what a circle is, but a circle does not normally have any lines passing through the center, so I don't understand how the lines fit in.  Do you mean "discs" instead of "circles"?

Comment: (If this is too difficult to explain in English, you can post in Spanish, and someone who understands Spanish will come and help you translate.)

Comment: @MJD Yes, I mean discs. I'm sorry.

Comment: So, aparently you know the definition. (Maybe you should include it in the original post.) Now, what is exactly your question?

Comment: @user126154 Apparently, the question is of the reference-request type. I edited to make this clear.

Comment: base elements contains its "center"? If yes, it seems to me that you get the discrete topology. If no, you get the usual topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not at all sure, but I *think* you might be describing what Seebach and Steen (*Counterexamples in Topology*) refer to as the “deleted diameter topology”.  Their description is:

> Let $X$ be the Euclidean plane, we define the deleted diameter topology on $X$ by taking as a subbasis for a topology $\sigma$ all open discs with all of the horizontal diameters other than the center, excluded.

(Section 76, page  95.)

That is, the sub-basic open sets consist of sets of the form $(C\setminus D_C)\cup\{O_C\}$ where $C$ is a disc, $D_C$ the diameter of the disc, and $O_C$ the center of the disc.

Google search for “deleted diameter topology” produces a number of hits, including [an item on the $\pi$-base web site](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000068).    [Here's the page about it on Austin Mohr's “Spacebook” web site](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=248&spaceID=76).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, he only list the properties of this topology but he does not describe or prove this properties.

Comment: What is « the diameter » of a disk?

Comment: It's a line segment  that passes through the center of the disc whose endpoints lie on the boundary of the disc.